# Javascript loop through XML from REST

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

How can I loop through diffferent child tags of upper tags wih javascript and print the tagname and value to HTML. A short example

```
<Product>
   <Books>
      <Genere>
         <Sport>
            <Name>Book A</Name>
             <Name>Book B</Name>
             <Name>Book C</Name>
          </Sport>
       <Genere>
         <History> 
           <Name>Book A</Name>
           <Name>Book B</Name>
           <Name>Book C</Name>
         </History>
      </Genere>
    </Books>
  <Product>
```

Let's say I would like to print the 6 book names in the following manner:

Name: Book A
Name: Book B
Name: Book C

Name: Book A
Name: Book B
Name: Book C

I took a look on W3C examples, but they were not really helpful.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to parse the XML string into an XMLDOM object. Then, you can use the various methods and properties of that object to navigate the nodes and get the data you want. I've added an example below. Note that there was a missing closing tag in your data (the first `<Genere>` node).

```js
//Function to parse XML string into an xml dom object
var parseXML = function(text){
  var xmlDoc;
  if (window.DOMParser){
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
  } else {
      // Internet Explorer
      xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = false;
      xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
  return xmlDoc;
}
//Function to get child nodes by name
var getChildrenByName = function(node, name){
  var childNodes = node.childNodes, matchingNodes = [];
  for(var i=0; i<childNodes.length; ++i){
    if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE && childNodes[i].tagName == name){
      matchingNodes.push(childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return matchingNodes;
}

//Test data
var data = '<Product><Books><Genere><Sport><Name>Book A</Name><Name>Book B</Name><Name>Book C</Name></Sport></Genere><Genere><History><Name>Book A</Name><Name>Book B</Name><Name>Book C</Name></History></Genere></Books><Product>'

//Execute parse
var doc = parseXML(data);

//Get Product node
var product = doc.firstChild;

//Get Books node
var books = getChildrenByName(product, 'Books')[0];

//Get genres
var genres = getChildrenByName(books, 'Genere');

//Loop through genres
var str = '';
for(var i=0; i<genres.length; ++i){
  var genre = genres[i].firstChild;
  str += '<h2>'+genre.tagName+'</h2>';
  //Get book names
  var bookNames = getChildrenByName(genre, 'Name');
  //Loop book names
  for(var j=0; j<bookNames.length; ++j){
    str += bookNames[j].textContent + '<br>';
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```